# Executing only the code of a page?

Tags: php, html, parsing

Hi guys consider I have a .php page that I need to include somewhere else.

page.php:

```
<?php 
 dosomecmd(); 
 doothercmd();
 //etc
?><html>pagehtml</html>
```

Is there a way to include this page but not printing the html inside? (I just need to execute those command)

I could do with ob

```
ob_start();
include('page.php');
ob_discard();
```

But i would prefer a faster way.

Thanks

Edit: i know i can sepearate html and php (and i already do) but that page.php is non else than a "static" cache I make, but sometimes I need to execute some command inside that cache instead to printing automatically it out

Edit2: of course i don't need everyime to not output the html (otherwise I could just delete all html) I need to return; only based on the results of my cmds up there

Thanks all i find a solution (add `return;`)

Comment: Sure: Open the file, copy-paste the commands in a new file, and run the new file. other than that, output buffer is your only hope.

Comment: output buffering is the faster way, also

Comment: You can use output buffering but it's a *very* ugly solution. It would be much cleaner to separate the code part and the HTML part, so the code part can be included separately.

Comment: for testing purpose, I often add an `exit()` at the end of the code, or a `die('debuging');`

Answer (score 3):

Would it be easier to have a common page with only the php that you need to share, and include it in both page.php and your other page?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to seperate with
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

also I wouldn't recommend that

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate the PHP logic at the start of your current script into another file, then include that into both of your scripts.